# How to avoid WKInterfaceTable overlapping the page control?

Tags: ios, watchkit

When I use the WKInterfaceTable along with a page control, the table contents overlap the page control. Is there a way to avoid this?

The view's architecture:

```
-Group
  -Label
  -Table
```

[image: Table content overlaps page control]

Answer (score 0):

Short of ensuring your views never require scrolling, there's no way to prevent this, unfortunately. It's come up on the dev forums numerous times, and no such API exists in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/watchkit).

Here's a link to a relevant post in the forums: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1100695#1100695

Even if you *could* do it, I think it would be fairly confusing to users to not know which page they were on in your navigation.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking to make the table shorter and ending before the dots starts, so you can see the dots at all time. An example of how that looks is when you scroll to the end of the table.